# Python: Trying to convert string to int, get error to int invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, string, recursion, error-handling, int

I am new to Python, so I apologize if this is a simple fix. I have been stuck on a Codeval problem (Happy Numbers) for quite some time and I am not sure what is going wrong.

**Problem Description:**

Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1, or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1.Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy, while those that do not end in 1 are unhappy.

**For example:**

7 is a happy number (7->49->97->130->10->1)

22 is not a happy number (22->8->64->52->29->85->89->145->42->20->4->16->37->58->89 ...)

**My test input and expected outcome:**

1    -->  1

7    -->  1

22   -->  0

If the number is a happy number, print out 1. If not, print out 0.

**Here is the full Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/happy_number.py", line 58, in <module>
    happy_number_check("happy_numbers.txt")
  File "/happy_number.py", line 55, in happy_number_check
    happy_or_not(line)
  File "/happy_number.py", line 33, in happy_or_not
    i = int(i)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**Here is my code:**

```
# test = 7


def happy_or_not(number):
    number = str(number)
    if number == 1:
        print 1
    else:
        new_num = 0
        for i in number:
            i = int(i)
            if i == " ":
                continue
            else:
                new_num += i**2
        if new_num == 10 or new_num == 10:
            print 1
        else:
            try:
                happy_or_not(new_num)
            except RuntimeError:
                print 0

# happy_or_not(test)


def happy_number_check(file):
    f = open(file, 'r+')
    for line in f:
        if line == "":
            continue
        else:
            happy_or_not(line)


happy_number_check("happy_numbers.txt")
```

**What I have already tried:**

Based on what I gathered from other similar questions, the issue may be that I am not able to convert a `str` into an `int` when I hit the line `i = int(i)`. It is my understanding that I have to convert the `str` type into an `int` type before doing any math on it, yet it looks like that is where it is failing.

I tested the `happy_or_not` function by itself, and it does print out the value that I expect it to. It seems like to me that the issue comes when I try and call that `happy_or_not` function inside of the `happy_number_check` function, which is reading my txt file (containing a list of numbers to test). I must not be grasping a larger principle here, so any explanations would be helpful.

This is also my first real attempt at a recursive function and there probably is a better way to structure this, so any suggestions on how to change things up to be more effective is most welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're trying to convert an empty string to an int, so it's failing. Try to debug through and find out why you're getting an empty string.

Comment: As the error says, you are sending `int()` an empty string. Don't send it an empty string.

Comment: You say `i = int(i)` then check whether `i == " "` which could never happen; an integer can't be a string with a single space.

Comment: You also say `number = str(number)` and then check whether `number == 1` which, again, could never happen.

Comment: Your file must have a line that is not empty (`""`) but still has a non-integer value, like `" "` (a single space). Try changing `if line == ""` to `if line.strip() == ""` in `happy_number_check`

Comment: Protip: when you need a new variable, use a new name.  Example: instead of `number=str(number)` use `str_number=str(number)`.  The Python interpreter accepts both, but your poor carbon-based brain works much better with the second than the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `happy_number_check` like this (validate each line is an integer):

```
def happy_number_check(file):
    with open(file, 'r+') as f:   # Safer way to open a file. Will automatically close for you even if something goes wrong
        for line in f:
            if line.strip().isdigit():
                happy_or_not(line.strip())
```

The `strip()` will also make it so that you can remove this code:

```
if i == " ":
    continue
else:
```

By the way, you also have a bug in your logic. You are relying on a RuntimeError - a Stack Overflow interestingly enough :-) - to terminate a test. You should really keep track of what numbers have been tried, and if you try the same number again, return 0.

Don't click this link if you don't want a straight up solution to the problem, but if you do, here is an iterative solution: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Happy_numbers#Python

Comment: Thank you! I got it working correctly. Now the fun part of refactoring out that other logic bug you mentioned. : )